# Maven copy external artifacts that are not dependencies of the project during build

Tags: java, maven

I'm looking for a way to copy jar files from the repo to a particular folder during build, to access this folder later on from the spring-boot webserver (e.g. /target/workspace/jars-go-here)

At first I had the maven-dependency-plugin in mind, but this does not seem to be capable of coping artifacts bundled within a pom as it does not work transitively for the goal 'copy'. 'copy-dependencies' does support copying the artifacts transitively, however only for dependencies of the project itself.
Next I've took a look on the maven-assembly-plugin. This supports copying jar of poms in a transitive way, but again only for dependencies of the project.

Is there a way to copy artifacts transitively that are NOT dependencies of the project itself?

Comment: That sounds like a contradiction in itself... If they are needed they should be dependencies of the project ??? Please give some real example

Comment: The idea is to load/enrich the spring-boot tomcat with some kind of plugins that are not really needed by the project itself for compilation but can optimally be used during runtime. Actually the assembly plugin would work for me, but than I would need to define the artifacts twice. Once in the assembly and once in the pom itself. Ideally I only have one place for that. And on top I looking for some kind of generic structure to apply it on further plugins.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more in detail about what kind of tomcat plugins you are talking about? Apart from that if those are only needed during runtime define them as dependencies with scope runtime ... and change the configuration of the spring-boot-maven-plugin to include runtime as well.... Furthermore it sounds as if you are using the maven-assembly-plugin wrong ... ???

Comment: @JimBob If they are used at runtime, they are dependencies.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I think you're right. I just wanted to find a way not to define them twice.
khmarbaise I need jars in a particular folder which the application will manually load in separate classloaders. But as JFabianMeier already wrote, they are technically runtime artifacts and should therefore be listed within the depedencies.